# Gram-Schmidt Procedure: What's the role of Schmidt in the derivation of it

Tags: linear-algebra, math-history

When reading the section related to Gram-Schmidt process in the book *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* by Gilbert Strang, I found a foot note that says:

> If Gram thought of it first, what was left for Schmidt.

Other books taught me that the two independently developed the method and many Internet sources also say the same thing (none go into the details of the contribution of each to the procedure). Thus, I suspect that prof. Strang seems to imply that Gram made the first contribution to the procedure but it was still incomplete and Schmidt later on handled the missing part (probably the part to normalize the basis vectors).

So what exactly did prof. Strang mean by adding the footnote?

This may seem to be off-topic but I can't find any site that is better than this to ask such question.

Comment: "This may seem to be off-topic but I can't find any site that is better than this to ask such question." - What about https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Asking about the contributions of various authors for a theorem does not seem off-topic to me, but maybe other people feel differently about this.

Comment: @Filippo, Ohm, I didn't know that site. Let me move it there and close it one.

Comment: Moved to other site at: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15998/gram-schmidt-procedure-whats-the-role-of-schmidt-in-the-derivation-of-it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question now was answered on HSMSE